# Angular2 scope's and components

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-directives, angular2-services

All,

This is what I have:

user-list.component.ts

```
export class UserListComponent {

    public userSerivce: UserService;

    public deleteUser(id) {
        this.userSerivce.delete(id);
    }
}
```

user-list.component.html

```html
<div>
    <some-reusable[deleteFunc]="delete" > </some-reusable><!-- this will bind "delete" on the user- list.component, to "deleteFunc" on  SomeReusableComponent-->
</div>
```

some-reusable.component.ts

```
export class SomeReusableComponent {    
    @Input() deleteFunc: Function;    
}
```

some-reusable.component.html

```html
<button type="button" (click)="deleteFunc(entityId)" aria-label="Delete" >
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"> </span>
</button>
```

This is my problem:

When i click the button it calls through to the function on the `UserListComponent` just fine, however when referring to `this` it refers too `SomeReusableComponent`, I understand why this is happening, but I'm looking for a solution? You can see in the above example the call to `this.userSerivce.delete(id);` will fail as `userService` does not exist on `SomeReusableComponent`.

I hope the above example makes sense.

Thanks

Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a better approach would be to use event binding

```ts
export class SomeReusableComponent {    
    @Output itemDeleted:EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();

    handleDelete(entityId) {
      itemDeleted.emit(entityId);
    }
}
```

```ts
<button type="button" (click)="handleDelete(entityId)" aria-label="Delete" >
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"> </span>
</button>
```

```ts
<some-reusable (itemDeleted)="delete($event)" > </some-reusable>
```

Comment: I was not aware of EventEmitter so thank you! This works a treat, would you consider this the best way at the moment for this sort of thing and is it future proof? Or do you think angular2 will handle this sort of scenario by itself in the future?

Comment: I think the way I demonstrated in my answer is the way to go in Angular2. If you still want to pass functions, use what Thierry explained in his answer, but I'd discourage if there are no strong reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Completely agreed with @Günter!

Regarding your `this` problem, it's because you lose the `this` when referencing a function (even from an object). To prevent from this, you could use the `bind` method of functions:

```
delete.bind(this)
```

Comment: Thank @Thierry for the info.